# How to make rectangle notch curve in bottomnavigationbar flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a BottomNavigationBar like below image:

[image: Rectangular curved]

But when i implement the code, i get a result like below:

[image]

My code:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          //elevation: 0.2,
          notchMargin: 7,
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          color: Color(0xff1c1f26),
          shape: AutomaticNotchedShape(
              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(15))),
              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)))),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 60,
          )),
      floatingActionButtonLocation:
          FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(17))),
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(Icons.favorite),
      )
```

what i need to do change or add to get a similar result like first image?

Comment: Where are you testing this code-snippet, can you include the regulation of the device? and I'm getting the same out as you expected , did you try rebuilding the app?

Comment: Using Android emulator. Yes i rebuild the app but same result.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of flutter SDK?

Comment: sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

Comment: Sorry , i'm unable to produce any issue in this code-snippet, you can try different emulator device,  `flutter clean` and run again, also hope you didn't change anything on source-code. try `flutter doctor -v` to check issue, or `flutter upgrade`  and can you provide same demo full widget including `main to end`  of code snippet that will produce the issue.

Comment: Ok, thanks bro. Problem solved as i run this in my android device. Maybe its a problem with my emulator. Thanks for the.

Answer (score 4):

Code Sample:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(),
        bottomNavigationBar: const BottomAppBar(
          notchMargin: 7,
          color: Color(0xff1c1f26),
          shape: AutomaticNotchedShape(
            RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                top: Radius.circular(15),
              ),
            ),
            RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
            ),
          ),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 60,
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(17))),
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Icon(Icons.favorite),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image: Output image]

> Flutter 2.5.3 Dart SDK 2.14.4

Comment: are there any changes on code-snippet?

Comment: Not really, that's why I mentioned the flutter and dart SDK version. But I believe there's some extra/unnecessary code too which I'm going to remove in an edit (now)

Comment: My versions are also same as you mentioned.

Comment: Ok, thanks bro. Problem solved as i run this in my android device. Maybe its a problem with my emulator. Thanks for the.